# Why button text displaying always white color in ie 8 browser?

Tags: html, css

I am using the below button style.

```
.button{
 border:1px solid #8dbdd8;
 color:#000000;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 width:50px;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-top: 0px;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#92cfde), to(#76bdd1));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #92cfde, #76bdd1);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #92cfde, #76bdd1);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #92cfde, #76bdd1);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #92cfde, #76bdd1);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #92cfde, #76bdd1);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#92cfde, endColorstr=#76bdd1);
}
.button{
 border:1px solid #44adc6;
 background-color: #8dbdd8; 
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6bbed2), to(#50abc4));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6bbed2, #50abc4);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6bbed2, #50abc4);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6bbed2, #50abc4);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6bbed2, #50abc4);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6bbed2, #50abc4);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#6bbed2, endColorstr=#50abc4);
}
```

the problem is i given text-color as black.but always showing white color only.this issue persist only user having ie8 browser as latest if user having ie9 it won't effect.please tell me how to resolve the issue in ie8 browser?

Comment: where's your html bits? or jsfiddle?

Comment: From what you have there I do not see you setting `color`. Ah I see, you now fixed the code.

Comment: Why two consecutive rules, with the same selector, setting the same properties?

Comment: Certainly seems like specificity issue

Comment: i'm check your code in `ie8` .its work and text is black,maybe another css code Influence the button

Comment: @Radian if u have ie9 as latest browser you won't get the issue.if u have ie8 as latest version then you can get issue.can you please check that and let me know the solution.

Comment: please tell me solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user3278026 i check in `ie8` please upload your document.